# dragdealer.js finding the value of step

Tags: jquery

i'm working with dragdealer.js http://code.ovidiu.ch/dragdealer/, and i'm facing problems in determining the slideshow.setStep() value.

I'm customizing the dragdealer example in a way that, when the value is slideshow.setStep(1) i'd like to show/hide different divs or add/remove classes.

i tried to get the value in animationCallback `var result = ((this.value.current)[0] * (this.steps - 1)) + 1;` but since thats during the animation it doesnt work fine. I want the value when the animation stops so i can do my show/hide divs.

The example of what ive done till now is here http://jsfiddle.net/tRjUC/2/

any help in this matter would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who still has this question should know that newer versions of Dragdealer have a `getStep` method built in: http://skidding.github.io/dragdealer/